# Why does catch block run?

Tags: javascript, ajax, asynchronous, promise

I have the following function which makes an ajax request o fetch data from an API.

```
function getSegements(url) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open('GET', url);
        request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');

        // request.onload = () => resolve(request.response);
        // request.onerror = () => reject(request.status);

        request.onreadystatechange = function() {

            if (request.readyState === 4)
            { 
                if (request.status === 200)
                {
                    data = JSON.parse(request.response);
                    console.log(data.segements);
                    resolve(data); 
                }
                else
                {
                    reject({status: request.status});
                }
            }
        };
        request.send();
    });
}
```

calling the function:

```
getSegements(url).then((data) => {
    //console.log(data);
    //data = JSON.parse(data);
    theWheel = new Winwheel({
        'outerRadius'     : 212,
        'textFontSize'    : 16,
        'textOrientation' : 'horizontal',
        'textAlignment'   : 'outer',
        'numSegments'     : data.no,
        'segments'        : data.segements,
        'animation' :           // Specify the animation to use.
        {
            'type'     : 'spinToStop',
            'duration' : 5,     // Duration in seconds.
            'spins'    : 3,     // Default number of complete spins.
            'callbackFinished' : alertPrize
        }
    });
    theWheel.animation.spins = 9;
    wheelSpinning = false;
})
.catch((err)=>{
    console.log(err);
    alert('Request failed.  Returned status of ' + err.status);
});
```

When there is a fault in WinWheel's parameter it runs the **catch** block. Why is running like that? Doesn't it depend on the function (in this case **getSegements**) if **then()** is going to run or **catch()**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`then()` returns a Promise as well, and uncaught exceptions are propagated through the call chain until `catch()` is found, and therefore `catch()` runs for any exception caught in a call chain

```js
new Promise((res, rej) => {
  res()
}).then(() => {
  throw "in then"
}).catch(e => console.log(e))
```

Comment: KITACE, How can I stop it from propagating to that specific catch()? I only want to use that catch block if function rejects?

Comment: @RafayHassan you either catch an exception in a function or follow Jonases' instructions

Answer (score 1):

Actually `.then` takes two arguments, one function called when everything is fine and one that gets called when an error occured in the previous chain. In your case you could write:

```
 getSegments(url).then(
   data => { new Whinweel() },
   error => console.log(error)
 );
```

Now using `.catch(handler)` is actually the same as `.then(null, handler)`, and as stated earlier, the error handler gets called if there was an error in the previous chain, including the previous "then" handler.

Comment: @JuanMendes, can you two elaborate it bit more?

Comment: @rafay no, because Juan did not read my answer carefully :)

Comment: That's why I deleted the comment :) But the question was closed because the pattern you mentioned is confusing and could miss exactly this case unless you're careful. Your example would miss errors caused by `new Whinweel`, I know that is what the OP wanted but seems like a bad idea

Comment: My point is that they are not equivalent. See this downvoted answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/53348246/227299

Comment: @juan yes, `.then(a).catch(b)` equals `then(a).then(undefined, b)` just as the answer says, it aas probably downvoted because it missed the point of that question

Comment: Yes, I realize that, but I think you would agree that is pretty confusing, and people are likely to write `then(a,b)` and expect it to catch errors in a .

Comment: @juan yes, but the OP wants that behaviour.